# Test if arguments match a function in R

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

Given a list of arguments, and a function, I'd like to see if I have a valid function call.

My attempt so far:

```
args_match <- function (fun, ...) {
  fun_name <- deparse(substitute(fun))
  safe_mc <- purrr::safely(match.call)
  x <- safe_mc(fun, do.call(call, list(fun_name, ...)))

  return(is.null(x$error))
}
```

This works for some functions:

```
> args_match(fivenum, y = 1:10)
[1] FALSE
> args_match(fivenum, x = 1:10)
[1] TRUE
```

But it fails for functions with a `...` argument:

```
> args_match(mean, x = 1:10)
[1] TRUE
> args_match(mean, y = 1:10)
[1] TRUE
> mean(y = 1:10)
Error in mean.default(y = 1:10) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a way to improve on this? The answer may be no, because some R functions indeed don't care if their arguments are missing... :-/

Comment: Notice that `args_match(fivenum, na.rm = 1:10)` also returns `TRUE`. I believe that in `R` it is not possible to know if some arguments will be properly evaluated without evaluating them.

Comment: Hmm. Looks as if the best thing might be to match arguments manually myself....